# IDLE failed to register a variable. How is that possible?

Tags: python, python-idle

I use python 2.7.6 with IDLE 2.7.6 on Microsoft Windows 7.

IDLE failed to register a variable (named `x5`), as shown in the image below. How is that possible?

[image]

---

Actions taken to trigger the issue:

1. The following is already in my IDLE console history:

   `>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))`
   `>>> x5 = 4`
2. I place the cursor somewhere on `x5 = 4`
3. I hit  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
4. This copies the following:

   `>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))`
   `>>> x5 = 4`
5. After copying, the cursor is automatically placed at the end of `x5 = 4`. I hit  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again, hoping that `x5` takes the value 4.
6. I type `x5` to check the value of `x5`. I get

   `>>> x5`

   `Traceback (most recent call last):`
   `File "<pyshell#118>", line 1, in <module>`
   `x5`
   `NameError: name 'x5' is not defined`

---

Based on Blckknght's answer and comments, it looks like I had copy pasted the following two lines at once (including the `>>>`) in the IDLE console in the first place:

```
x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x5 = 4
```

As a result, the line `>>> x5 = 4` was simply ignored, since IDLE only cares about the first python statement it sees.

---

The entire IDLE log:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> '#' *3
'###'
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.random((3, 3))
>>> b=np.random.random((3, 3))
>>> a
array([[ 0.92731349,  0.48377097,  0.32175387],
       [ 0.65061308,  0.72905101,  0.65499733],
       [ 0.1334612 ,  0.4023123 ,  0.50179231]])
>>> b
array([[ 0.35232561,  0.77837691,  0.70645223],
       [ 0.51114669,  0.83303289,  0.78842767],
       [ 0.51179183,  0.25109079,  0.91229917]])
>>> a*b
array([[ 0.32671629,  0.37655615,  0.22730374],
       [ 0.33255872,  0.60732347,  0.51641802],
       [ 0.06830435,  0.10101691,  0.45778471]])
>>> a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]

>>> b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]

>>> a = [[3, 4], [2, 1]]
>>> a
[[3, 4], [2, 1]]
>>> b
[[4, 1], [2, 2]]
>>>  np.dot(a, b)

  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1
    np.dot(a, b)
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> np.dot(a, b)
array([[20, 11],
       [10,  4]])
>>> a = [[1, 2]]
>>> a.dot(b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    a.dot(b)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dot'
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2]])
>>> a.dot(b)
array([[8, 5]])
>>> a = np.array([[3,4]])
>>> b= = np.array([[3,4]])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> b= np.dot(a, b)
 np.array([[3,4]])

>>> a*b
array([[60, 44]])
>>> a
array([[3, 4]])
>>> b
array([[20, 11]])
>>> np.dot(a, b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    np.dot(a, b)
ValueError: objects are not aligned
>>> 
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(3.0)

>>> np.multiply(x1, x2)

array([[  0.,   1.,   4.],
       [  0.,   4.,  10.],
       [  0.,   7.,  16.]])
>>> x1
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
>>> z2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    z2
NameError: name 'z2' is not defined
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> np.multiply(x1, x2)
array([[  0.,   1.,   4.],
       [  0.,   4.,  10.],
       [  0.,   7.,  16.]])
>>> x1
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0)
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = 3
>>> x2
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
>>> x1=1
>>> x1
1
>>> x2 = 3
>>> x2
3
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0)
>>> x2
3
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0)
>>> x2
3
>>> x1
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
>>> x1x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0)
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(9.0)
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))

>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x3 = np.arange(9.0)
>>> x3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#60>", line 1, in <module>
    x3
NameError: name 'x3' is not defined
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x3 = 4
>>> x3

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    x3
NameError: name 'x3' is not defined
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x4 = 4
>>> x4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#64>", line 1, in <module>
    x4
NameError: name 'x4' is not defined
>>> 
>>> 


>>> 



>>> 

>>> 


>>> 

>>> 

>>> 

>>> 

>>> 

>>> 

>>> 

>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x4 = 4
>>> x4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    x4
NameError: name 'x4' is not defined
>>> x4 = 4
>>> x4
4
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x4 = 4
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x5 = 5
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x5 = 4
>>> x5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#84>", line 1, in <module>
    x5
NameError: name 'x5' is not defined
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x5 = 4
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x5 = 4
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x5 = 4
>>> x5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#104>", line 1, in <module>
    x5
NameError: name 'x5' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: It is python, not IDLE that executes your code, and that is generating the error message.  Something seems faulty in your installation.  What happens if you do the same in interactive Python without IDLE?  Please copy and paste the interaction into your question.  It is impossible to do anything with a jumpy video.  I strongly recommend you upgrade to 2.7.12.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy The issue appears only when I copy the previous code using the  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  keyboard shortcut. If I type `x5  = 4`, then it does work. So I think IDLE is messing up something. I have I did the entire IDLE log in the question.

Comment: Does one of your `x5` names have an invisible control character next to it? If you're copying and pasting the name one of the times but not the other, this could explain the issue.

Comment: @Blckknght What's the best way to check for the presence of invisible control character? According to http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/string-functions.php# there is no hidden character: `>>>[Space]x5[Space]=[Space]4[End of Line(LF)]`. I also try moving the cursor one character at a time and didn't see anything suspicious.

Comment: Try adding quotation marks around the line in IDLE after you've copy/pasted it? That should give you the `repr` of the line, which should show special characters with escape sequences.

Comment: @Blckknght `>>> "x5 = 4"` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Note that if after copying the previous code using the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keyboard shortcut, I change `x5` with something else, the same issue occurs.

Comment: I was hoping for something more minimal '-).  In any case, please explain *precisely* what actions you mean by "<kbd>ENTER</kbd> keyboard shortcut".  There is "click on a previous statement and hit <ENTER>", which copies the entire statement, and "select part of a previous statement and hit <ENTER>", which copies only the selected part.  Both work fine in my installed 2.7.12.  Experimenting, I discovered to my surprise that both also work on non-code text.  Once, when I select code and the previous prompt space, " x5", IDLE froze.  But after restarting, I could not reproduce.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Sounds good, I have added the steps in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're copying multiple lines at once. When that happens in Python 2.7's version of IDLE, it ignores all the statements after the first. So your `x5` line never runs, and the name is not bound to anything.

You can see that the color of the `>>>` characters in your animation at the start of the `x5` lines are different than one the other lines. When they're copied they are black like other entered text. When they are an actual prompt, they're red (in the default color scheme at least).

You can avoid this issue by highlighting just one line of code and pressing ENTER to copy only it, not the whole entry it was part of.

In Python 3, it's an error to provide multiple statements at the same time in the IDLE console (it says `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement`).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense (even though I don't understand why IDLE would choose to only execute the first line). By the way, how comes clicking on one line and hitting enter copies multiple lines at once?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it only does that with the ENTER-to-copy method if the previous version of the lines were also pasted all at once (perhaps with CTRL+V from somewhere else).

Comment: Thanks, everything is clear, I can now fully reproduce the behavior I was showing in the question.

Comment: What the video shows is that either you selected from 'x1' up to '= 4' on the next line, including the prompt in between, or that IDLE in that version on your machine acted as if you did.  That does not explain why the existing binding of x5 got erased.  With 2.7.12 on Win10, clicking on one statement only copies one statement.  If I select two lines as described, the binding of x5 is not deleted.  I suggest again that you upgrade and try again.

Comment: <The above was written while the previous 2 comments that made it obsolete were posted.>  I can see now in the video that the `>>> ` prompt in the first instance of `x5 = 4` is black, so that the assignment was never made.  As for your other question, IDLE's Shell is Python aware and works with Python statements, not physical lines. This makes normal interaction with multiline statements easier.  Accepting multiple statements in one paste could probably be made to work, but is not trivial.